# Docker copy from one container to another

Tags: asp.net, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY MyApp.Api/MyApp.Api.csproj MyApp.Api/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyApp.Api
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
copy --from=build["C:\Program Files\nodejs", "C:\nodejs"]
RUN SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\nodejs"
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.Api.dll"]
```

And I want to copy nodejs from **c:\Program Files\nodejs on build** to **C:\nodejs on final**.
But when I build it i get this error:

> Step 15/19 : copy --from=publish ["C:\Program Files\nodejs",
>   "C:\nodejs"]
>
> ERROR: Service 'myapp.api' failed to build:
>   failed to process "[\"C:\Program": unexpected end of statement while
>   looking for matching double-quote

How can I copy nodejs from the build image to my final image?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're missing a space before the opening double quote. Plus, are you sure the syntax allows using an array as the copy command argument?

Comment: Yes, this is from the Docker reference documentation:
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] ["<src>",... "<dest>"] (this form is required for paths containing whitespace)

Comment: Uhm, I think the square brackets indicate a custom field, but you should omit them from the actual command

Comment: I tried removing the brackets, and I'm getting similar error:
ERROR: Service 'myapp.api' failed to build:failed to process "\"C:\\Program": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote

Comment: i deleted my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `copy --from=publish ["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs", "C:\\nodejs"]` gives:

```
ERROR: Service 'myapp.api' failed to build: COPY failed: 
 CreateFile \\?\Volume{acdcd1b2-fe0d-11e7-8a8f-10f00533bf2a}\C:Program Filesnodejs:
```

Try double-escape:

```
copy --from=publish ["C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs", "C:\\\\nodejs"]
```

Or consider as [in this Dockerfile](https://github.com/monamimani/msbuildDocker/commit/f39ab049e9212f236c0dddc830a19a8519290830) the alternative syntax:

```
copy --from=publish C:\Program Files\nodejs C:\nodejs
```

However, that [aforementioned dockerfile](https://github.com/monamimani/msbuildDocker/blob/f39ab049e9212f236c0dddc830a19a8519290830/Dockerfile#L57-L70) does use both syntax without any issue. For example:

```
COPY --from=SetupPhase ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs"]
```

But: it does, before the `copy --from`:

```
RUN icacls 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules' /reset /t /c /q 
RUN attrib -h -r -s 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules' /s
RUN attrib -h -r -s "C:/Windows" /s
```

(Replace those paths by the one you want to access)

That might explain why it can copy from another Windows image: no access problem because the ACLs were reset.

The [OP Luka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305813/luka) confirms:

> 1. Add these lines to build
>
>    ```
>    RUN icacls "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs" /reset /t /c /q 
>      RUN attrib -h -r -s "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs" /d /s
>    ```
> 2. Edited the copy line in final to this:
>
>    ```
>    COPY --from=build ["C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs", "/nodejs"]
>    ```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I updated my question with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Luka Well done! SO you needed both: the iacl and the double escape!

Comment: Yes.
I needed both.